# How to conventionally set the LifeTimeManagement in a UnityContainer?

Tags: c#, unity-container, ioc-container

In my app, I use a messenger interface `IMessagePublisher<T>` in a generic realization class `SimpleMessenger<T>`. For a same type `T`, there must be one and only one `SimpleMessenger` instance wich has to be `ContainerControlledLifetimeManaged` without possible exception.

I use RegisterTypes to automaticaly do most of my registerations :

```
unityContainer.RegisterTypes(
            AllClasses.FromAssembliesInBasePath(),
            WithMappings.FromAllInterfacesInSameAssembly,
            WithName.Default,
            WithLifetime.None,
            null,
            true
            );
```

And to my great surprise, it appears that the container manage to automatically register all my SimpleMessengers ! While unexpected, it's potentially a good news. That is, if I manage to conventionally set the lifetime to `ContainerControlledLifetimeManagement` for all my IMessagePublisher realizations.

In a few words, I would like to add to my container a "Registeration strategy" which would say something like

```
if(somehowObtainedTypeToRegister.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IMessageListener<object>).GetGenericTypeDefinition())
{
     //Set one way or another the ContainerControlledLifetimeManagement for this type
}
```

But I have no idea how to do this. I already use a `UnityContainerExtension` but it seems to be useful only at Reslution time, not at Registeration time. Is it some way to achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to map it would be to do it twice, e.g.:

First register all mappings as you did before. Then override all items where you want to be handled by the `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager`:

```
unityContainer.RegisterTypes(
    AllClasses.FromAssembliesInBasePath()
        .Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Any(
            i => i.IsGenericType
            && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IMessageListener<>))),
    WithMappings.FromAllInterfacesInSameAssembly,
    WithName.Default,
    WithLifetime.ContainerControlled,
    null,
    true);
```

Comment: I just came back to answer my own question as I found this out on my own but your linq query is way better than mine (I was doing my test on SimpleMessenger in place of IMessageListener). Also, +1 000 000 for learning me the utility af Any() AND that you can use typeof(Generic<>) ( I was doing typeof(Generic<object>).GetGenericTypeDefinition()...)